# Cursor hovering over placeholder in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The cursor is hovering above the placeholder in this one UITextField, instead of in line with it like it should be (see image below for the problem). There is no change in code that affects this particular instance.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
private func setupOTPField() {
    otpField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    otpField.returnKeyType = .continue
    otpField.placeholder = OTP_FIELD_PLACEHOLDER
    self.addSubview(otpField)
}
```

The setStyle function is called on most UITextFields:

```
extension UITextField {
    func addBottomBorder() {
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: self.frame.size.height - BOTTOM_BORDER_HEIGHT,
                                  width: self.frame.size.width,
                                  height: BOTTOM_BORDER_HEIGHT)

        if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            bottomLine.backgroundColor = BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_DARK_MODE
        } else {
            bottomLine.backgroundColor = BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR
        }

        borderStyle = .none
        layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }

    func setStyle() {
        addBottomBorder()
        font = .systemFont(ofSize: FONT_SIZE)
        backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR
        textAlignment = .center
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the cursor position.
[image]

I checked the other UITextField instances in my app - they have identical code and the cursor is behaving normally there.

Comment: Hi, lizardcoder!  When you have a question about specific code on StackOverflow, it helps us answer your question if you format it in code blocks instead of as images.  Please take a look at this discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors .  I have suggested an edit to your post that applies the kind of formatting that is expected on this site, but the changes won't be visible until you or someone else approves the edit.  Best wishes finding a solution - I'm interested to see what's causing the cursor problem too!

Comment: Hi Quake E. Duck - thank you very much. Your suggestions are helpful, and I will adjust future questions I have to more closely meet community standards.